# I need to iterate and compute Nested Map<key, someObjectArray[]>

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I need to iterate a Map with Key and List to provide another type of object. I have tried to explain in the code level.

I have tried with for loop which works fine. But I like to have in Java8 streaming

```
public Map<String, List<TestClassResult>> getComputed(
    Map<String, SourceClass[]> sourceMapObject) {

Map<String, List<TestClassResult>> response = new HashMap<>();
// Here goes the functionality
List<TestClassResult> result;
for (Map.Entry<String, SourceClass[]> entry : sourceMapObject.entrySet()) {
      result = new ArrayList<>();
      String key = entry.getKey();
      for (SourceClass value : entry.getValue()) {
        result.add(someMethod(value.id, value.empCode));
      }
      response.put(key, result);
    }
return response;
}

public class SourceClass{
   private String id;
   private String empCode;
}

public class TestClassResult{
   private String empName;
   private String empMartial;
   private int empAge;
}
```

I need this to be implemented with Java 8 streams and lambdas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sourceMapObject.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                     Entry::getKey,
                     entry -> Arrays.stream(entry.getValue())
                                   .map(value -> someMethod(value.id, value.empCode))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList()),
                     (left, right) -> right                                          
))
```

If you know for sure you will not have duplicates you can omit the `(left, right) -> right` part. But since in your existing code, you had `response.put(key, result);` I'd kept it to conform to that.

The point here is that `Map::put` will override the previous value that you already had in the `Map`, while a `Collectors::toMap` *without* a merger will throw an Exception. On the other hand with `(left, right) -> right`, it will behave just like the `put`.

Comment: While checking I can see the following error message. Can you please help with this?

{Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R, A> collect(Collector<? super T,A,R>)}

Comment: Eugene, I've made a slight correction and formatted the details. Please feel free to rollback if any of that conflicts your intention. @mani Try the updated code. It shall work.